# What does RWD theme name stands for?

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, rwd-theme, rwd

What does RWD theme name stands for?

Just wondering what does it mean?

I keep reading it as 'rear wheel drive' in my head, help.

Comment: Responsive Web Design

Comment: @Himanshu cool, make an answer for me to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RWD stands for 'Responsive Web Design'.